# Weird Console.log: 10 error in google plus login using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, google-plus

I am trying to implement `google-plus` login using firebase in my Ionic3/Angular application for Android/iOS. I am using [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) plugin and [ionic-native-google-plus](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus/) for google plus login for my application.

I followed this [tutorial](https://chriztalk.com/ionic-2-firebase-google-authentication/). But, i am getting an weird **console.log: 10** error while trying to login in the android device.

**Note:** Right now, i am using my debug certificate in the firebase for android.

I have found an existing issue [link](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/243) for this specific problem. I have tried everything of there but nothing is working for me. It is taking toll on me for 2-3 days.

Can anyone point me out what could be the solution to avoid this weird error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a error 10 and found a fix, perhaps this will work for you too:

I replaced what I had in webClientId with a different id and that did the trick. I just had to go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and under "OAuth 2.0 client IDs" I got the id for the "Web Client".

So as long as you use that for your id and the correct SHA1 for the .keystore used to sign your .apk, then it should work!